# Is it possible to calculate the correlation coefficient between two samples with different sizes

Tags: correlation

I have a sample_1 of 1000 elements.
For this sample_1 I applied a window transform with a window size of 10 and got a sample_2 of 991 elements. Now I want to calculate correlation coefficient between them. Is it possible to calculate correlation coefficients between two samples with different sizes?

Comment: you need to define a correspondence between the series and truncate the longer one

Comment: @gunes: That looks like an answer, can you write it as a formal answer?